# Reference for monotonicity: $x\geq y\implies x\succsim y$ and $x>y\implies x\succ y$

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, preferences, theory

I've seen this definition for monotonicity many times on different papers and on this site:

> $x\geq y\implies x\succsim y$ and $x>>y\implies x\succ y$.

However, what I read on MWG's microeconomic theory textbook is:

> Definition of monotonicity: $x>>y\implies x\succ y$.

Here $x>>y$ means $x_i>y_i$ for all coordinates $i$.

My question: what some famous **references** for the first definition of monotonicity?

Answer (score 2):

MWG defines two types of montone preferences (definition 3.B.2).

For a first they define preferences to be **montone** if $y \gg x$ implies that $y \succ x$. Here $y \gg x$ means that every component of the vector $y$ is strictly larger than every corresponding component of the vector $x$. (e.g. $y = [1,1]$ and $x = [0.5, 0]$)

For the second, they define preferences to be **strongly monotone** if $y \ge x$ and $x \ne y$ then $y \succ x$. This means that $y$ contains at least as much of every component as $x$ but is not equal to $x$ (so one component should be strictly larger. For example if $y = [1,1]$ and $x = [1,0]$).

From your question, it is unclear what you mean by $y > x$.

- Does you mean that $y \ge x$ and $x \ne y$, then both your definitions are basically the definition of strict monotonicity as in MWG (as $x \ge y$ and not $x > y$ is the same as $x = y$).
- Does it mean that $y \gg x$, then your second definition boils down to the definition of monotonicity as in MWG.

Comment: $y>x$ means $y>>x$. I am interested in the reference for the first definition in the question.

Comment: @HighGPA The handbook of Jehle and Reny (Advanced Microeconomic Theory) uses your first definition (axiom 4 on page 10, I have the 3rd edition) and call it Strict Monotonicity. Maybe you can use this as a reference.

Comment: This is great!!